# How to implement a translate + scale animation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation

I have a screen with an Image at one corner of the screen and I want to animate it to the centre of the screen.
Something like going from

```kotlin
Icon(
    painter = //,
    contentDescription = //,
    modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp)
)
```

to

```kotlin
Icon(
    painter = //,
    contentDescription = //,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```

The first one is placed at the top left corner of screen and the second one at the centre. How can I animate between the two states?

Comment: Well if it is to occupy the entire screen width, you just need to animate the size of the icon. It will automatically be centred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make animations work in Compose you need to animate a value of some particular modifier. There's no way how you can animate between different set of modifiers.

Following [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#gesture-and-animation) documentation paragraph, you can animate value for `Modifier.size`.

First I wait for the size of the image to be determined, with this value the `size` modifier can be set (I use `then` with an empty `Modifier` before that) and then this value can be animated.

Here's a sample:

```
Column {
    val animatableSize = remember { Animatable(Size.Zero, Size.VectorConverter) }
    val (containerSize, setContainerSize) = remember { mutableStateOf<Size?>(null) }
    val (imageSize, setImageSize) = remember { mutableStateOf<Size?>(null) }
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Button(onClick = {
        scope.launch {
            if (imageSize == null || containerSize == null) return@launch
            val targetSize = if (animatableSize.value == imageSize) containerSize else imageSize
            animatableSize.animateTo(
                targetSize,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000)
            )
        }
    }) {
        Text("Animate")
    }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .size(300.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .onSizeChanged { size ->
                setContainerSize(size.toSize())
            }
    ) {
        Image(
            Icons.Default.Person,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .then(
                    if (animatableSize.value != Size.Zero) {
                        animatableSize.value.run {
                            Modifier.size(
                                width = with(density) { width.toDp() },
                                height = with(density) { height.toDp() },
                            )
                        }
                    } else {
                        Modifier
                    }
                )
                .onSizeChanged { intSize ->
                    if (imageSize != null) return@onSizeChanged
                    val size = intSize.toSize()
                    setImageSize(size)
                    scope.launch {
                        animatableSize.snapTo(size)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please mention which dependency is required for the DpSize class? I am not able to import it.

Comment: @ArpitShukla my bad. `DpSize` is introduced in Compose `1.1.0-beta`, see updated answer without it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one out:

```
@Composable
fun DUM_E_MARK_II(triggered: Boolean) {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        val size by animateDpAsState(if (triggered) 36.dp else maxHeight)
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Warning,
            contentDescription = "Just a better solution to the problem",
            modifier = Modifier.size(size)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The gif is a bit laggy, but that is error in recording. The actual animation is pretty smooth.

Comment: So, what makes you think that this is not the correct solution? It is more effective compared to the marked answer.

Comment: This is the easier solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone needs the maximum height of the screen for that `maxHeight` parameter, you can get it by calling `LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp` within a Composition Scope, thought it might help.